# Why does following C code print 45 in case of int 45 and 36 in case of STRING and ASCII value of CHAR?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-construction, char

```
struct s{
int a;
char c;
};
int main()
{
    struct s b = {5,'a'};
    char *p =(char *)&b;
    *p = 45;
    printf("%d " , b.a);
    return 0;
}
```

If `*p` is changes to any `character` than it prints `ASCII`   value of character  , if `*p`  changed to any `string ("xyz")` than it prints `36` . Why it's happening ?

Can you give memory map of structure s and *p ?

According to me mamory of struct

`s as z-> (****)(*) assuming 4 byte for int .` and when s initialize than it would have become `(0000000 00000000 00000000 00000101)(ASCII OF char a)` and *p points to starting address of z . and *p is a character pointer so it will be store ASCII value at each BYTE location i.e. at each * will be occupied by ASCII of char . But now we make it to 45 so z would have become  `(45 0 0 5 )(ASCII of char a)` . But it's not true why ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   Be more Specific ..

Comment: BTW: it depends also if you work with little or big endian.

Comment: Is the main point of the question why a whole int seems to be written when you write to a char with *p = 45?

Comment: `string("foo")` most certainly isn't C.

Comment: @Jarod42 it only works for little endian, at big endian the output would be 754 974 725

Comment: @user3805652 _'Be more Specific'_ That needs a bigger machine :D ...

Comment: 0xAABBCCDD is stored 0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA on little-endian architectures e.g. x86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write to the struct through a `char *` pointer, you store `45` in the first byte of the struct. If you are on a Little-Endian implementation, you will write to the low end of `b.a`. If you are on a Big-Endian implementation, you will write to the high end of `b.a`.

Here is a visualization of what typically happens to the structure on an implementation with 16-bit ints, before and after the assignment `*p=45`. Note that the struct is padded to a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.

#### Little-Endian

```
Before:  a [05][00]  (int)5
         c [61]
           [  ]

After:   a [2d][00]  (int)45
         c [61]
           [  ]
```

#### Big-Endian

```
Before:  a [00][05]  (int)5
         c [61]
           [  ]

After:   a [2d][05]  (int)11525
         c [61]
           [  ]
```

With larger ints, there are more ways to order the bytes, but you are exceedingly unlikely to encounter any other that the two above in real life.

**However**, The next line invokes **undefined behaviour** for two reasons:

```
printf("%d " , b.a);
```

1. You are modifying a part of `b.a` through a pointer of a different type. This *may* give `b.a` a "trap representation", and reading a value containing a trap representation causes undefined behaviour. (And no, you are not likely to ever encounter a trap representation (in an integer type) in real life.)
2. You are calling a variadic function without a function declaration. Variadic functions typically have unusal ways of passing arguments, so the compiler has to know about it. The usual fix is to `#include <stdio.h>`.

Undefined behaviour means that anything could happen, such as printing the wrong value, crashing your program or (the worst of them all) doing exactly what you expect.

Comment: How to know it's Big or Little- Endian ?

Comment: you are on little endian if the result is 45

Comment: yeah but there is any way to check it ?

Comment: I edited a test program to my answer. But you could read the documentation of your cpu

Comment: `unsigned char` has special privileges. You can store a small number,  such as `1`, in an `int`, and check (through an `unsigned char *`) if the first byte is `0` or `1` without causing undefined behaviour. If it is `0`, it is BE.

Comment: Endian-ness depends on your computer hardware. Usually you just know. Depending on your compiler and operating system, you can usually find some #defines that the compiler implicitly sets up for you that tell you whether it's big- or little-endian, you can usually find info on that in your compiler's or operating system's documentation.

Comment: @mch  Why the result is different in case of String?

Comment: @NisseEngström Why the result is different in case of String ?

Comment: the chars of an char array are in a row and not affected by little or big endian, therefore a string has the same memory look in little and big endian

Comment: do not make it complicated LSB (little endian) AND MSB (big endian) the BIG ENDIAN is FROM LEFT TO RIGHT (ENGLISH WRITING) AND LITTLE ENDIAN IS FROM RIGHT TO LEFT (ARABIC IN WRITING).

example: supposed you have HEX: AA BB CC DD

big endian 1000: AA 1001: BB 1002: CC 1003: DD
little endian 1000: DD 1001: CC 1002: BB 1003: AA

thats simple as that!

Comment: the hard disk and your memory is JUST A ONE LARGE ARRAY.

Comment: @NisseEngström: can you explain better why is it UB?

Comment: @user3805652: I have no idea what "**`*p` changed to any `string ("xyz")`**" means, so I didn't respond to it.

Comment: @dmcr_code: Modifying part of an object through a pointer of another type _may_ cause the original object to contain a **trap representation**. Reading a trap representation causes undefined behaviour. See [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **6.2.6 Representation of types**. The wording in my original answer was incorrectly based on an entirely different situation.

Comment: @NisseEngström: do you refer to strict aliasing? I thought you could cast to unsigned char/char ptr types ..

Comment: @mch But output is always 36 in case of String . You can check it with any string. Why it's ?

Comment: @user3805652 that's the address of `"xyz"` saved in an char, so it is the same as `b.a = "xyz" % 256;` including compiler warning and so on. Compile with other optimization and you will probably get an other number.

Comment: @mch I got always same number (36) .

Comment: @user3805652 and i got 252, 20 or 228. `*p = "xyz";` was the line? It really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

your struct looks in little endian like:

```
00000101 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001
```

so `p` points to the `5` and overwrite it. at the printf the 4 little endian bytes print the `45`.

if you would try it on big endian `754974725` would be the result, because `p` points to the MSB side of the int.

a simple test program to find out if you are on little or big endian:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 0x12345678;
  unsigned char *c = (unsigned char*)(&a);
  if (*c == 0x78)
    printf("little-endian\n");
  else
    printf("big-endian\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The C standard guarantees that the address of the first member of a structure is the address of the structure. That is, in your case,

`int* p =(int*)&b;`

*is* a safe cast. But there is no standard way of accessing the `char` member from the address of the structure. This is because the standard does not say anything about the contiguity of successive members in memory: in fact the compiler may or may not insert gaps (called structure packing) between members to suit the chipset.

So what you're doing is essentially undefined.

Comment: standard way you are correct - but practically on a x86 machine, the pointers is used to access the beginning of the memory space of the `b` struct.

Comment: If I'm working on the Mars lander (1/2 million lines of C) I don't give two hoots about "practically", *only* about the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Because, this

```
*p = 45;
```

Changes the value of what p points to to 45. And you made p point to b.

Answer (score 0):

try this Pointers to structure.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    struct s{
    int a;
    char c[1];
    };

    int main()
    {
        struct s *p;
        struct s b = {5, 'a'};
        p = &b;

        printf("%d %s", p->a, p->c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if  you want Pointers as structure member instead of an array of char.
try this..

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct s{
int a;
char *c;
};

int main()
{
    struct s b = {5, "a"};

    printf("%d %s", b.a, b.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`char *p = (char*) &b;` - in this line, `p` points to the beginning of `b` struct as a char pointer.

`*p = 45;` writes 45 to the memory space of `b` which is can be accessed by `b.a` as well.

when you print `printf("%d ", b.a);` you'll print the 45 stored in the stack memory assigned as `a` member of `struct b` you'll get 45.

try debugging it yourself and you'll see it in the watch window

Comment: `p` points to the first byte of `b`, but `b.a` is the first 4 bytes of `b`

Comment: @mch - as 45 occupies only 1 byte, then printing the first 4 bytes of `b` makes the same result

Comment: @user3805652 i don't follow your updated question - it is too much confusing